# iOS: Child View Controller dismissal causes viewDidLoad to be called again

Tags: ios, dismissviewcontroller

I have a view controller, `SubscribeVC` which uses InAppPurchases service which is injected into it. The user initiates the purchase logic and during the process, `StoreKit` shows few `UIAlertControllers` regarding the purchase that is about to be made. On the view controller I hold strong reference to the (InAppPurchases) service, and calls a function which has a completion handler for when the purchase completes.

The problem is that when the user dismisses the StoreKit's alerts, it makes `SubscribeVC` to be reloaded (Which calls viewDidLoad etc.), and to the completion handler to cause `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error (because it was released when the VC instance was) when completes.

I open `SubscribeVC` through AppDelegate and I also tried to hold a strong reference to the `SubscribeVC` instance from within the InAppPurchases service but nothing helps, `SubscribeVC` is still being reloaded some how.

What am I doing wrong? Any Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well apparently I instantiate the `UIViewController` `SubscribeVC` from `applicationDidBecomeActive` of `AppDelegate`. When StoreKit's alert was dismissed, `applicationDidBecomeActive`  was called again, reinstantiated `SubscribeVC` and reassigned `AppDelegate's` `window.rootViewController` to the newly instantiated VC, which caused the original VC to be released from memory.

The solution is to instantiate the view controller from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, which is being called once when the application launches.

Hope it'll help someone.